# How to copy coupled classes

Tags: c++

I want to have generic variables that I can easily write to / load from XML file and possibly use in a menu system. A class holding such variables would look like

```
class Entity
{
private:
 VarGroup group;

 Var<float> myfloat;
 Var<int> myint;

public:
 Entity() : group("group name"), myfloat("name", &group), myint("name2", &group) {}
};
```

`Var` is equipped with overloaded operators, so I can use them like regular variables. They are given literal names and their base class pointers are inserted to group. `VarGroup` is then used to perform bulk actions on `Var` types, such as import to/from XML.

The problem is that if Entity objects are stored in `std::vector` by value, the data may be moved in memory and the `Var` pointers in `VarGroup` object become invalid.

Is it possible or even reasonable to attempt to handle this type of copy by functionality within `Var` and `VarGroup`?

More details:

```
class VarBase
{
protected:
 std::string name;

public:
 VarBase(const std::string &_name) : name(_name) {}
 virtual bool toXMLNode(rapidxml::xml_document<> *doc, rapidxml::xml_node<> *parent) const = 0;
 virtual bool fromXMLNode(rapidxml::xml_node<> *node) = 0;
 std::string getName() const;
};

class VarGroup
{
private:
 std::string name;
 std::vector<VarBase*> vars;

public:
 VarGroup(const std::string &_name) : name(_name) {}

 void insert(VarBase *var)
 {
  vars.push_back(var);
 }

 bool toXMLNode(const std::string &nodeName, rapidxml::xml_document<> *doc) const;
 bool fromXMLNode(rapidxml::xml_node<> *node);
};

template<typename T>
class Var : public VarBase
{
private:
 T value;

public:
 Var(const std::string &_name, VarGroup *group) : VarBase(_name)
 {
  group->insert(this);
 }

 bool toXMLNode(rapidxml::xml_document<> *doc, rapidxml::xml_node<> *parent) const override;
 bool fromXMLNode(rapidxml::xml_node<> *node) override;

 // Implementations of operators (), =, etc.
};
```

Comment: The problem domain is called serialization. Take a look at boost::serialization.

Comment: Maybe you could make it so that `VarGroup` actually *owns* the data, e.g. by being a container of unique pointers?

Comment: You should show some more details about `VarGroup` and `Var<>` declarations, to get good answers about what should be refactored.

Comment: @erenon : Serialization is part of the intent, though I'm not sure I wan't to introduce boost dependency to my project. I'm thinking of using rapidXML, although this is not relevant for the topic.

Comment: @KerrekSB : I probably can't make the variables unique pointers in `VarGroup` if I want to store the variables also in `Entity` for quick access. Although, storing the data in `VarGroup` could probably solve the copy issue. Would it make sense to store them in `VarGroup` and have pointers or references of `Var` in `Entity`? Then again, copying `Entity` would require the setup of these pointers.

Comment: On short term, an easy way to solve the problem would be to let Entity setup the `Var` objects on copy, but I would have to implement such behavior for all Entity-like classes and I have reason to believe that there will be many such classes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to think of an approach, but it may be dangerous.

I added VarGroup pointer to Var class to make the two coupled in both ways. I then added copy constructors that attempt to retain proper coupling under copy of either class and this must be order-independent.

```
class VarBase
{
protected:
 std::string name;

public:
 VarBase(const std::string &_name) : name(_name) {}
 virtual bool toXMLNode(rapidxml::xml_document<> *doc, rapidxml::xml_node<> *parent) const = 0;
 virtual bool fromXMLNode(rapidxml::xml_node<> *node) = 0;
 std::string getName() const;
};

class VarGroup
{
private:
 std::string name;
 std::vector<VarBase*> vars;

public:
 VarGroup(const std::string &_name) : name(_name) {}

 VarGroup(const VarGroup &that)
 {
  name = that.name;
  vars = that.vars;

  for(auto base : vars)
   base->pGroup = this;
 }

 // Swap existing VarBase pointer with new one.
 void swap(VarBase *newVar, VarBase *oldVar)
 {
  auto it = find(vars.begin(), vars.end(), oldVar);
  *it = newVar;
 }

 void insert(VarBase *var)
 {
  vars.push_back(var);
 }

 bool toXMLNode(const std::string &nodeName, rapidxml::xml_document<> *doc) const;
 bool fromXMLNode(rapidxml::xml_node<> *node);
};

template<typename T>
class Var : public VarBase
{
friend class VarGroup;
private:
 T value;
 VarGroup *pGroup;

public:
 Var(const std::string &_name, VarGroup *_pGroup) : VarBase(_name), pGroup(_pGroup)
 {
  pGroup->insert(this);
 }

 Var(const Var &that)
 {
  pGroup = that.pGroup;
  value = that.value;

  pGroup->swap(this, &that);
 }

 bool toXMLNode(rapidxml::xml_document<> *doc, rapidxml::xml_node<> *parent) const override;
 bool fromXMLNode(rapidxml::xml_node<> *node) override;

 // Implementations of operators (), =, etc.
};
```

Now, there are two copy cases:

1) `VarGroup` object is copied first.

It accesses the "to be copied" `Var` objects to change their group pointer to new one.
When the `Var` objects are copied, they copy the new `VarGroup` address from the old `Var` object. Then via that new pointer, they call the new `VarGroup` object to change its old `Var` object address to new one.

2) `Var` objects are copied first.

The copy constructor copies the old group address (redundant operation). Then it swaps the `Var` address from the "to be copied group". When the `VarGroup` object is copied, it already has the new `Var` addresses (if all `Var` objects have been copied). It then accesses the new `Var` objects to change their group pointer to a new one.

This sounds overly complicated, but might it just work?